# Converting a list of lists into a multi-dimensional list in python

Tags: python, list, fortran

I have manipulated a dataset into looking something like this:

```
# data_dict = { 'epoch':[[int(n), int(m), int(c + cs), int(s + ss)], ...], ... }
```

where every key (`'epoch'`) is associated with a list of lists that look something like this:

```
# [1, 0, (c + cs)_10, (s + ss)_10]
# [2, 0, (c + cs)_20, (s + ss)_20]
# [3, 0, ...]
# [4, 0, ...]
# [5, 0, ...]
# [1, 1, ...]
# [1, 2, ...]
# [1, 3, ...]
# [1, 4, ...]
# [1, 5, ...]
#    .
#    .
#    .
# [5, 5, (c + cs)_55, (s + ss)_55]
```

What I want is to be able to access any value of `(c + cs)_mn` given an `'epoch'` and values for `m` and `n`.

My initial thought is to somehow convert each list of lists into a multidimensional list, so I would be able to see the values I want by calling `data_dict['epoch'][m][n]`. Is it possible to do this?

Going further, is it even feasible to do this? The raw data is FORTRAN-formatted, but I know nothing about FORTRAN. As a result, I have taken this (admittedly convoluted) approach to converting the data into something easily readable.

For reference, the data I am looking at can be found [here](http://puu.sh/nzgfy/c7639d998a.txt).

Comment: Looking at your data from the link it looks trivial to organize into a dictionary based on the first three columns where the values are the rest of the columns (epoch, m, and n). But in your dictionary, I don't see where to get the epoch names to put into the key with the m and n values.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire I was avoiding sharing my code because it's a hot mess right now, but since you asked, here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/HotelCalifornia/3b224891ff45156de494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how your data looks now the brute force would just be

```
for item in your_list:
   if item[0] == m and item[1] == m:
       return item[2]
```

Given how your data is structured now you can do the following

```
new_dict = {}
for row in data_dict['epoch']:
    if new_dict.get(row[0]):
        new_dict[row[0]].update({row[1]:row[2]})
    else:
        new_dict[row[0]] = {row[1]:row[2]}
return_data = {'epoch':new_dict}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the second bit is trying to do?

Comment: I'm creating a dictionary that will look like
{ 'epoch': { 1 : {  0 : (c + cs)_10, 1: (c + cs)_11} ,
               { 2 : {  0 : (c + cs)_20, 1: (c + cs)_21} 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for v in data_dict['epoch']:
    d.setdefault(v[0], {})[v[1]] = v[2]
```

Or using Python's built-in `defaultdict` you can easily get it

```
from collections import defaultdict
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()
for v in data_dict['epoch']: d[v[0]][v[1]] = v[2]
```

`data_dict = {'epoch':d}`

you can calling `data_dict['epoch'][m][n]` to get value.

Comment: Please consider adding a commentary on why your code is the best solution to problem

Comment: Can you offer any explanation of what `defaultdict` does in this situation?

Comment: @HotelCalifornia use `defaultdict` build a tree of data structure